# SELECT data from 4 tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with MySQL statement:

```
  SELECT 
      oxarticles.OXTITLE AS TITLE, 
      oxmanufacturers.OXTITLE_1 AS OXMANTITLE,
      oxarticles.OXDISTEAN AS OXDISTEAN,
      oxarticles.OXMPN AS MPN,
      oxarticles.OXPRICE AS OXPRICE,
      oxarticles.OXSTOCK AS OXSTOCK, 
      oxarticles.OXARTNUM AS OXARTNUM, 
      oxseo.OXSEOURL AS OXSEOURL, 
      oxartextends.OXLONGDESC_1 AS OXLONGDESC 
  FROM `oxarticles` 
    INNER JOIN `oxartextends` ON oxarticles.OXID = oxartextends.OXID 
    INNER JOIN `oxmanufacturers` ON oxarticles.OXID = oxmanufacturers.OXID 
    INNER JOIN `oxseo` ON oxarticles.OXID = oxseo.OXOBJECTID;
```

My problem is that tables `oxarticles` and `oxmanufacturers` have two same column names `OXID` and `OXTITLE_1` but the above code doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Waht's the issue? Are you sure to join over OXID column?

Comment: well yes i am sure but i have OXTITLE_1  in both table so how do i select it , above sql returns empty result.

Comment: I don't understand wich the problem is.

Comment: @ericpap above statement returns empty result

Comment: What do you mean with empty result? no records? or oxmanufacturers.OXTITLE_1 is empty value?

Comment: As all the column references are fully qualified then the fact that the names are the same is not important. you need to look elsewhere for the issue of no rows being returned.

Comment: Maybe use transactions?

Comment: @RyanVincent you are correct no rows are being returned.

Comment: You don't have a WHERE clause so all records from your tables should be select

Comment: @ericpap yes they should but not working since i have added `oxmanufacturers`

Comment: Why don't you post some data sample of every table and the field types? your problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: Does oxmanufacturers table have data? or is empty?

Comment: Does the value of field OXID in table oxmanufacturers matches the value of same field on oxarticles table? Are both field types the same?

Comment: @ericpap yes `OXID` matches and `oxmanufacturers`  data.

Comment: Then i don't understand what the problem is. You should post data sample then.

Comment: @ericpap here is my sample data https://gist.github.com/itsbalamurali/10287806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match article id to manufacturer id. That's wrong. You need to join your article table to the manufacturer table using the manufacturer id, not the article id.

In your case, that is `oxarticles.OXMANUFACTURERID` for the manufacturer id in the article table and `oxmanufacturers.OXID` in the manufacturer table.

```sql
SELECT 
      oxarticles.OXTITLE AS TITLE, 
      oxmanufacturers.OXTITLE_1 AS OXMANTITLE,
      oxarticles.OXDISTEAN AS OXDISTEAN,
      oxarticles.OXMPN AS MPN,
      oxarticles.OXPRICE AS OXPRICE,
      oxarticles.OXSTOCK AS OXSTOCK, 
      oxarticles.OXARTNUM AS OXARTNUM, 
      oxseo.OXSEOURL AS OXSEOURL, 
      oxartextends.OXLONGDESC_1 AS OXLONGDESC 
  FROM `oxarticles` 
    INNER JOIN `oxartextends` 
      ON oxarticles.OXID = oxartextends.OXID 
    INNER JOIN `oxmanufacturers` 
      ON oxarticles.OXMANUFACTURERID = oxmanufacturers.OXID 
--                                             ^^^
--                                             Here's the manufacturer id 
--                                             in the article table

    INNER JOIN `oxseo` 
      ON oxarticles.OXID = oxseo.OXOBJECTID;
```

Comment: This db design is really not very verbose... What kind of shop is that?

Comment: well i dont know i am just taking csv of db thats it :)